# Problem linking to tutorial in Workbench / DocumentationTools

Tags: packages, documentation, workbench

I've picked up Workbench / DocumentationTools again to add some new tutorials.  Everything was going fine until I tried to use the "Link to Tutorial" button in DocTools.  Didn't work, and I got some error messages in the console:

```
StringMatchQ::strse: String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringMatchQ[$DocumentationDirectory,*/]. >>

StringMatchQ::strse: String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringMatchQ[$LinkBase,|Whitespace]. >>
```

The neighboring B-button was even worse.  Any ideas on what happened to my previously working setup?  I'm using Workbench 10.1.822 and Mathematica 10.0 to make documentation (12.1 is my daily driver) on MacOS 10.14.6.

[image: screenshot showing problem]

Comment: As far as I know, this is hopelessly broken.  If anyone knows what the current state of affairs is, please share.

Comment: @HirenPatel Did you encounter the same problem?  Because Workbench / DocuTools has been working OK for me until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  I needed to hit the `Select Paclet Name & Path` button and then select the top folder containing my paclet.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Happened again (after reinstalling Mathematica, so maybe that's the cause?).  Glad to have figured it out before and answered my own question so I could look up how to fix it!